# increment not working inside advanced for loop

Tags: java, selenium

From the below method every time the line "System.out.println("J incremented to : "+j)" printed as 2. I dont know why. Pls anyone suggest me.

```
for(WebElement e : RefereceRange)
        {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",e);
            int j=1;
            if(e.isSelected())
            {
                e.click();
                j++;
                System.out.println("J incremented to : "+j);
            }
            if(j==size)
                break;
        }
```

Comment: because you set j to 1 **inside** your loop.

Comment: You define `j=1` then increment it... I don't see what you don't understand. Maybe you wanted to initialize `j` outside of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

I assigned j inside the for loop. so it assigned to 1 every time the loop continues. Now I declared j above for loop. It works

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is inside loop, every time is born new.
Move before loop, ant rethink You want count from one or from zero

```
     int j=1; // maybe You want zero ???

     for(WebElement e : RefereceRange)
        {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",e);
            if(e.isSelected())
            {
                e.click();
                j++;
                System.out.println("J incremented to : "+j);
            }
            if(j==size)
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `j` is affected to 1 every time. If ou want to keep incrementing it, you have to instanciate it outside your loop.

```
int j=1;
for(WebElement e : RefereceRange)
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",e);

        if(e.isSelected())
        {
            e.click();
            j++;
            System.out.println("J incremented to : "+j);
        }
        if(j==size)
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the declaration of `int j = 1` out of the loop, instead you say each time you loop « reset `j` to `1` », so with the increment, it will always print `j` as `2`.

```
int j = 1;
for(WebElement e : RefereceRange) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",e);

    if(e.isSelected()) {
        e.click();
        j++;
        System.out.println("J incremented to : "+j);
    }
    if(j==size)
        break;
}
```